# Unable to observe CLAMAV antivirus logs at Log Explorer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, antivirus, clamav

We are using `Clamav anti virus` at GCP Compute Instances.

It is required to persist the antivirus scan logs for 365 days as per compliance.

Though log archiving is already present at our GCP logs, but I am unable to find any log generate by clamav or clamscan

I have also tried *manually running the clamscan*, but still do not observe the logs at GCP's `Log Explorer`

If possible please help me with below queries

1. How to view clamav/clamscan logs at GCP `Log Explorer` ?
2. If any other better approach for persisting clamscan/clamav logs, then please guide.

---

Manual Running clamscan

[image]

No observation at log explorer
[image]

Comment: AFAIK Clam Antivirus is not integrated with Google Cloud Logging. That means you will need to set up Clam to log and then set up Cloud Logging to copy those log entries.

Answer (score 0):

To configuring ClamAV to Generate Logs in GCP:

You need to specify the log file. When running clamscan, specify a log file using the -l option to direct the output to a log file.

`clamscan -l /path/to/clamav.log.`

Then verify that the log file location is accessible and monitored by GCP's Logging service to capture ClamAV logs.

Manually run `clamscan` with the specified log file option to trigger ClamAV scans and generate logs that can be monitored. Navigate to GCP's Log Explorer interface to search for and view logs generated by ClamAV.

Comment: clamscan is alreadu pushing logs at `/var/log/clamav`

Comment: Make sure the SA associate with your VM has permissions (logging.logWriter) to write logs to Logging.

Comment: @danyL Yes.. VM is already writing logs to Log Explorer